# How to override the Release.namespace for subcharts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a parent chart which contains 4 subcharts, out of these I want to deploy the 1 specific subchart to different namespace and all the template files in that subchart are referring to `{{ .Release.Namespace. }}`. Is their any way to modify the `.Release.Namespace.` of subchart from the parent chart?

Comment: How are you using and calling the sub-chart? This might be possible by changing the scope you pass.

Comment: I'm calling the subchart from the parent chart using 'helm install -n namespace', but I don't want this namespace or release name to go down to specific subchart and I need to override its value. my release and ns are same, which I don't want only to this specific subchart.

Comment: I think I do really need to override the "Release" name for this subchart by storing the value I need somewhere, not sure specifically how to do it.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet where the sub-chart is used in your chart

Comment: ah sorry not sure which code you will require, because my parent chart has a directory called charts inside that I have 4 sub-charts and all these 4 sub-charts take values from the parent chart values.yaml. My directory or code structure is similar to storing subcharts under the parent chart.

Comment: Did you make all of these charts from scratch? Do you reference them via dependencies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using vanilla Helm and charts you don't control.

When a chart depends on a subchart, there's fairly little that it's possible to customize.  The parent chart can provide a default set of values for the subchart, but nothing computed, and those can be overridden by the person running `helm install`.

If, and only if, the subchart is specifically written to deploy into an alternate namespace

```yaml
# Every object in the subchart must have this configuration
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace | default .Release.Namespace }}
```

then you could supply that value to the subchart; but this isn't a default configuration.

My general experience has been that Helm "umbrella charts" are inflexible in a couple of important ways.  There are higher-level tools like [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) and [Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) that provide a single-command installation of multiple Helm charts with a full set of options (Helmsman is simpler, Helmfile allows Helm-style templating almost everywhere which is both more powerful and more complex).  If you need to install four charts, three into one namespace and one into another, these tools might work better.